# How to put listen over $destroy while using controllerAs syntax in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angularjs-lifecycle

Now I'm getting rid of `$scope` dependency from my angular controller to ensuring that I could easily migrate my code to Angular2. My current angular version is `1.4.X`.
While doing the same thing there is place while I placed `$destroy` listener over my controller scope like `$scope.$on('$destory', function() ....)`.

I can see `$on` method only available on `$scope` of controller, but how can I achieve it without using `$scope` dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using angular 1.5+ they added [lifecycle hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture) that you can opt into on your controller.  No `$scope` needed.  Just add a function called `$onDestroy()` to your controller and it will be called when your controller is being clean up:

> `$onDestroy()` - Called on a controller when its containing scope is
>   destroyed. Use this hook for releasing external resources, watches and
>   event handlers.

Example from http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2016/03/29/exploring-angular-1.5-lifecycle-hooks.html:

```
function MyCmpController($element) {

  var clickHandler = function () {
    // do something
  };

  this.$onInit = function () {
    $element.on('click', clickHandler);
  };

  this.$onDestroy = function () {
    $element.off('click', clickHandler);
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this too. Mine answer just solves the problem till 1.4.X version, but your solution looks promising to me as it will work for 1.5+, basically I had my project on 1.4.X version and was struggling to make it working from couple of hours and `$element.$on('$destroy',...)` working.. So I added it, Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

After some research I found that the `$destroy` event is emitted while removing DOM & on that same DOM scope it broadcasts `$destroy` event, but at the same time same that event has been propagated on `DOM` which is going to be removed.

You know there is one dependency `$element`, if you inject that in controller will give you the DOM where you have `ng-controller` directive place. So inject `$element` inside your controller & then place listener over it like below

```
$element.on('$destroy', function(){
   //write clean up code here
});
```

> Mine solution will work till 1.4.X version. For 1.5.3+ version you
>   could use Angular `lifecycle hook` which is `$onDestroy` like shown by
>   `@pgreen2` in above answer. Thanks :)